# Y-axis values not ordered

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

When I plot my data, the y-axis values are not sorted, as shown below.

[image]

This is the data frame.

[image]

At first, I had to convert the numbers into `str`, because it didn't let me plot `float` values or `ints`, but now that the values are `str` they don't sort at the time of plotting them.

This is the code for the plotting:

```
plt.plot(df.columns[1:-2],df.iloc[1, 1:-2],)
plt.title('Inversion MOP 2021, Dir. Arquitectura')
plt.ylabel('Millones de pesos')
plt.xlabel('Region')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: 1. The values must be numeric type. 2. These are discrete categories, and should be plotted as a bar plot, not a line plot.